# ImageIO always throwing exception

Tags: background, ioexception, javax.imageio

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    File f;
    BackgroundPanel(File file) {
        f = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Image image;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(f);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            image = null;
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 850, 1100, this);
    }

}
```

I hope the issue I am having is not too specific to find some help. This is always throwing an exception for -specific- files. I loaded one of the sample jpgs from my windows folder and it loads fine. The jpgs that I need to use, however, will not load in. I am confident I am using the right file path, and if I use a canRead(), it returns true. I really can't figure out why it wouldn't be loading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should of course never do I/O in the paintComponent (or on the Swing event dispatcher thread in general), but that is not the reason for the exception. What exception do you get (stacktrace)? Maybe you could post a sample file that fails?

Answer (score 0):

canRead() is not useful. Because image = ImageIO.read(f); canRead() will be called in read() function. If canRead() return false, it will throw IOException("Can't read input file!");  If you are not sure about the correct of your  file path, you should put sample jpgs and specific jpgs together. I conside the probleam is in your jpgs files. They are not decoded as jpgs by ImageIO.read().